# When would I need to rollback an NHibernate transaction when it fails on commit?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions

I'm following [this example on how to implement session-per-request](http://www.piotrwalat.net/nhibernate-session-management-in-asp-net-web-api/) transactions in NHibernate.

I've got the following:

```
public class SessionManagementAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

    public SessionManagementAttribute()
    {
        SessionFactory = WebApiApplication.SessionFactory;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        var transaction = session.Transaction;
        if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
        {
            //  TODO: Do I need to rollback a transaction here?
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
        session.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering -- if my transaction commit fails and an NHibernate exception is thrown -- should I be catching that and rolling back the transaction? In my current code I have an explicit catch and rollback. For example,

```
public void Save(Video video)
{
    try
    {
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.BeginTransaction();
        DoSave(video);
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception);
        NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.RollbackTransaction();
        throw;
    }
}
```

but I've seen hints through my readings that this might not be necessary. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

We always have to handle the session. Either if all goes ok, but even if something goes wrong. Take a look at these: [6.5. Lazy Initialization](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-lazy) *(cite)*:

> In a web-based application, an event handler can be used to `close()` the `ISession` only at the very end of a user request, once the rendering of the view is complete. **Of course, this places heavy demands upon the correctness of the exception handling** of your application infrastructure. **It is vitally important that the ISession is `closed` and the `transaction` ended** before returning to the user, even **when an exception occurs during rendering of the view**. The event handler has to be able to access the ISession for this approach.

Another place: [9.2. Loading an object](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading) *(cite)*

> ... Note that `Load()` will throw an **unrecoverable exception** if there is no matching database row.

But mostly the:

#### [9.8. Exception handling](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions)

An extract:

> If the ISession throws an exception **you should immediately rollback the transaction, call ISession.Close() and discard the ISession instance**. Certain methods of ISession will not leave the session in a consistent state...

Documented example:

```
ISession sess = factory.openSession();
try
{
    // do some work
    ...
    sess.Flush();
    currentTransaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    currentTransaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
finally
{
    sess.Close();
}
```

#### Summary

Other words, session handling is our responsibility. We have to be sure that the rollback is called regardles some "external circumstances" which could do rollback on connection close... We also have to be sure that the session is correctly exposed at the end

Comment: Just a quick curious question, do we *really* need to close/discard the session if an error has surfaced, or will transaction rollback suffice? If we do need to dispose it, why? Because "certain methods of ISession will not leave the session in a consistent state"? I don't really understand it. :/

Comment: @JWLim The transaction and session are different concepts. Almost independent *(while we still profit from both of them used together)*. If there is a **rollback**, other then planned *(e.g. unit tests)*, it almost always does mean, that something wrong - unintended has happened. And all the related data *(kept in session)* are in that moment inconsistent ***(changed, in session, but not in persistence)***. So YES `rollback()` and `session.close` / `dispose` should go explicitly together.

Comment: So if I'm using a session-per-request approach and opening/closing a session at the start/end of every request, do I need to implement a method to close/reopen a new session every time I rollback?

Comment: The comment is too small place to describe ASP.NET web-form. But in case of the ASP.NET MVC or Web API it is pretty straightforward. Web API has get/read operations separated from write operations. So any PUT, POST or DELETE would succeed (comit) or rollback. In MVC, we can rollback in one Action, and the `Redirect` to another. Both in fact are represented by different context == different session per request. *The ancient Web-Form world is more complex topic*. But I would say, that these principles *(mentioned above in my answer)* could be applied in per request session world easily.